# Cross-compile a gnulib based project to MinGW

Tags: c, cross-compiling, autotools, gnulib

I am trying to cross-compile this [project](https://github.com/akodakim/shill) to MinGW.

The project uses autotools as the build system, and depends on [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), [CUnit](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/), [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) and some gnulib modules.

I have all the dependancies compiled for `x86_64-w64-mingw32` and installed under `/home/user/mingw64`

I run:

```
$ gnulib-tool --update
$ autoreconf -fi
$ CURL_CFLAGS="-I/home/user/mingw64/usr/local/include" \
CURL_LIBS="-L/home/user/mingw64/usr/local/lib -lcurl" \
JANSSON_CFLAGS="-I/home/user/mingw64/usr/local/include" \
JANSSON_LIBS="-L/home/user/mingw64/usr/local/lib -ljansson" \
CUNIT_CFLAGS="-I/home/user/mingw64/usr/local/include" \
CUNIT_LIBS="-L/home/user/mingw64/usr/local/lib -lcunit" \
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
$ make
```

And I get this error:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/projects/shill'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/projects/shill/po'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/projects/shill/po'
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/projects/shill/lib'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'lib/errno.h', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/projects/shill/lib'
Makefile:1897: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/projects/shill'
Makefile:1429: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`errno.h` is part of the gnulib modules. So I think that the problem comes from this section in the [Makefile.am](https://github.com/akodakim/shill/blob/master/Makefile.am):

```
# Find gnulib headers.
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

AM_CPPFLAGS = \
  -DLOCALEDIR='"$(localedir)"' \
  -Ilib -I$(top_srcdir)/lib \
  -Isrc -I$(top_srcdir)/src \
```

But I can't figure out the solution. I followed exactly the instructions described in the [gnulib manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/).

Comment: In some Makefile there's a line like `all: ... lib/errno.h ...` (or a line that expands to that after variable substitution) that's the proximate cause of your problem.

Comment: @RossRidge All the `Makefile`s are auto-generated by autotools so even if I can find the error and fix it, it wouldn't work. The `Makefile`s will be regenerated and override the fix.

Comment: So fix it by modifying the source.

Comment: That's what I couldn't do, Can you help with that? It would be nice :D

Comment: Is gnulib built? (Do you have a libgnu.a somewhere? An errno.h somewhere? Yes -> Include path issue. No -> Build dependency issue.

Comment: No, gnulib is not built yet. And there is no errno.h. That's where the problem is. errno.h should be generated from errno.in.h. It fails right before that.

Comment: No, I can't help you because I don't have the source.

Comment: @RossRidge All the sources are available on [Github](https://github.com/akodakim/shill).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround for this issue. Apparently `autotools` aren't as easy as I thought they are.

1. I had to regenerate `gnulib` modules, this time specifying the
   `--makefile-name` parameter. ie.

   ```
   $ gnulib-tool ... --makefile-name=gnulib.mk ...
   ```
2. I removed `lib/Makefile` from automake generated files in `configure.ac`. So instead of:

   ```
   dnl Put automake generated files results here
   AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
          po/Makefile.in
          lib/Makefile])
   ```

   Now I have:

   ```
   dnl Put automake generated files results here
   AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
              po/Makefile.in])
   ```
3. I removed `lib` form `SUBDIRS` in `Makefile.am`. ie. Instead of:

   ```
   # Subdirectories to descend into.
   SUBDIRS = po lib
   ```

   I have:

   ```
   # Subdirectories to descend into.
   SUBDIRS = po
   ```
4. I created a new file in `lib` directory called `local.mk` with this content:

   ```
   include lib/gnulib.mk

   # Allow "make distdir" to succeed before "make all" has run.
   dist-hook: $(noinst_LIBRARIES)
   .PHONY: dist-hook
   ```
5. And included it in `Makefile.am`.

   ```
   include $(top_srcdir)/lib/local.mk
   ```
6. Finally I had to run this command:

   ```
   $ ./build-aux/prefix-gnulib-mk --lib-name=libshill lib/gnulib.mk
   ```

That was it.

Comment: Well done and a good beginning on Stackoverflow! It's great that you took the time to document here what worked for you. Keep it up!